# How to set the Google map type?

Tags: ol3-google-maps

How do I set the Google map type e.g. SATELLITE or TERRAIN? I tried varitaions of the OpenLayers 2 syntax:

```
new olgm.layer.Google( { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE });
```

and

```
new olgm.layer.Google({ 
    params: { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE }
});
```

but no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
new olgm.layer.Google({
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};
```

See a [live example](http://mapgears.github.io/ol3-google-maps/examples/dist/examples/concept.html) (click on the **+ Satellite** button).  See also the [JavaScript source file of the example](http://mapgears.github.io/ol3-google-maps/examples/dist/examples/concept.js)

Answer (score 0):

See exemple:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 21,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: { lat: ..., lng: ....},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });
```